# Qt iOS build does not find headers with path

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I am building a working application (`Mac` and `Linux`) for `iOS emulator` in `Qt 5.4` but when compiling the sources, compiler shows issues about header files not found. These files definitely are where they should be and the same code/pro builds without issues for desktop versions.

For example, in my code I have included:

```
#include <sndfile.h>
```

and in my `.pro` file I have:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lsndfile.1
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
```

and the header file for `libsndfile` is definitely in `/usr/local/include`

I have tried adding this to `.pro` file

```
INCLUDEPATH+= $PWD
```

But no use, still all headers that are not directly in the same folder
as the `.pro` file cannot be found when compiling... What am I missing?
Is there some different way to define paths to iOS build sources?

I am able to build `Qt` `iOS` tutorial projects and run them on the `emulator`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Makefile is outdated.
Run qmake again, after changing something in .pro file.